# How can I save a vector to a binary file?

Tags: c++, object, vector, binaryfiles

this is what I have:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void saveVector(vector<ObjectName*>);
vector<ObjectName*> readVector();

int main(){
    vector<ObjectName*> objects;


    int option;
    cin >> option;

    switch(option){
        case 1:{
        //read vector
            for(int i =0; i < readVector().size(); i++){
                objects.push_back(readVector()[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            //save vector
            objects.push_back(new ObjectName());
            saveVector();
            break;     
        }        



    return 0;
}

void saveVector(vector<ObjectName*> objects){
    ofstream fout("./Binary/ObjectsData.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
    int size1 = objects.size();
    fout.write((char*)&size1, sizeof(size1));
    fout.write((char*)objects.data(), size1 * sizeof(int));
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
}


vector<ObjectName*> readVector(){
  vector<ObjectName*> list2;

  ifstream is("./Binary/ObjectsData.bin", ios::binary);
  int size2;
  is.read((char*)&size2, 4);
  list2.resize(size2);

  is.read((char*)&list2[0], size2 * sizeof(list2));
  is.close();

  return list2;

}
```

ObjectName is just a name for any type of Object.

What am I doing wrong? If I get the "objects" vector size and compare it to the "readVector()" vector size (after executing the program and saving the vector for the first time) it shows that they have the same size, but if I try to add another object to the "objects" vector I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Is there a better way to save and read the objects and add them back to a vector?

Comment: Adding `#include<vector>` may help somewhat.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to save pointers to a binary file.

Comment: What the heck is an `ObjectName`? and `ObjectType`?

Comment: @user4581301 Doesn't matter much for that specific case.

Comment: Your code is total mess, saveVector changes signature, and inside it uses some `consolas` which is defined nowhere. In `readVector` you do something very strange: `is.read((char*)&list2[0]`. list2[0] returns a pointer to ObjectName*, so using & on it returns address of location of this pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No I guess not. Andre, can we get a [mcve] here?

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ serialization vector".  The term *serialization* is about reading and writing items (in native format).

Comment: sorry for the mess, I was trying to re-write the code from Spanish variables names to English (since my native tongue is Spanish) so I forgot to change some of the variable names

Comment: I'm going to edit the code and add the right variable names

Comment: A vector of pointers isn't what you usually want. A vector objects destroys the objects it contains when it goes out of scope. Now in saving any vector to a binary stream, you have to answer two questions, how do I know how many items are in the vector? and how do I know where one item begins and the other ends?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you have a *lot* of problems in here, and ultimately you're going to just need to go back to a good C++ tutorial and just learn the language.  You're getting way ahead of your current understanding of the language, here.

But, a big one is that you're saving out the *pointers* to your objects, not the objects themselves.  You can't save pointers from a previous execution of your program and then use them in a subsequent one.  Pointers are only valid between when you allocate the memory they're pointing to and when you explicitly `delete` them or the program ends.

What you'd need to do is save each object individually—the pointed-to object, not the pointer itself—and then, one at a time, create objects, read them in from your file, and add the pointers to them to the vector.

Or, you could store the objects directly in the vector, not just pointers to them.

But, either way, none of this will work if your objects aren't Plain Old Data, because otherwise they'll have things like vtables in them that you can't save.  In that case, you need a more sophisticated serialisation approach than just dumping the memory out to disk and reading it back in.

Comment: yeah I just re-wrote the code that I had (I use variable names in Spanish) incorrectly. What I meant to do was saving the elements of the vector that contains pointers to objects, so I know I have to dereference them but that is only if I want to store the objects in a binary file one by one. But what I want to do is save a vector containing pointers to objects to a binary file, is that a bad idea?

Comment: The problem is that the vector doesn't contain the objects, it contains pointers to the objects.  By just saving the raw memory of the vector's contents, all you're saving is the pointers, not the objects they're pointing to.  

If you want to save all the objects with a single memory dump, you'll need to use a `std::vector<ObjectName>`, which stores the objects themselves in the vector, not a `std::vector<ObjectName*>`, which just stores pointers to the objects.  Otherwise, you'll have to save the objects one at a time by dereferencing them.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try and save just the objects, and not the pointers

Answer (score 1):

First, write a function that serializes an individual object.  This could be the `<<` operator for `std::ostream`.  Then, write a `for` loop or `std::for_each` call that iterates over the vector and serializes each object.  Store the objects themselves in the vector, not pointers to them (or if you want to store pointers or smart pointers later, you can dereference them in your `for` loop).

Simple example that isn’t a complete answer to your problem:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;

int main(void)
{
  std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};

  for ( const int &i : v )
    cout << i << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can write binary data instead of string data with `std::ostream::write()`.  If you actually care about cross-platform compatibility, you’d convert first into a standard format that specifies layout and endianness, but you probably don’t, so writing `sizeof(x)` bytes at the address `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&x)` should be good enough.  This will only work for types that are Plain Old Data.

Comment: Thanks for the help